# How to update MySQL database column by performing api call on each row in one column

Tags: python, mysql, cron

So far, whenever user input's a country name my program will grab list of cities from json file and for each city it will perform api call and retrieve data for each city which is then stored into mysql database.

```
id   country    cities       lat    lng   aqi
 1    Canada    Toronto     x      y     13
 2    Canada    Vancouver   x2     y2    55
 .... and so on for all canadian cities.
```

Aqi, air quality index is measure of pollutant in our atmosphere and it gets updated regularly so in the morning it might be low but during rush hour times it might increase therefore it is important to have it updated.

My goal is to perform api call for each city within cities column and use it to update aqi column.

Also when user input new country it will add more data at end of database table I want it to update as well so as user inputs more country database will be greater and more updates.

I've read about cron job and mysql event scheduler however having a hard time combining it with api calls.

I want it to update every one hour.

Here is my code:

When user inputs country, JS sends variable to python and waits for response
var country_search = d3.select("#submit")

```
country_search.on("click", function(){
    d3.event.preventDefault();

    var user_input_country = d3.select("#user_country").node().value;
    d3.select("#user_country").node().value = "";

    clean_format(user_input_country, function(cleaned_input){

        d3.json(`/cities/${cleaned_input}`, function(error, response){

            setTimeout(function(){ markermap(response) }, 3000); // this inserts map in to tag that has id="map"
        });

function clean_format(user_input_country, callback){
    const splitted = user_input_country.split(" ");
    // if no space in country name
    if (splitted.length === 1){
        cleaned_input = user_input_country.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + user_input_country.slice(1).toLowerCase()
    }
    // if space --> titlecase all other than of/and,...etc.
    else{
        for (var i=0; i <splitted.length; i++) { 
            // titlecase if word is not "of" or "and"
            if (splitted[i] != "of" && splitted[i] !="and"){
                splitted[i] = splitted[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + splitted[i].slice(1).toLowerCase()
            }
        }
        cleaned_input = splitted.join(" ")
    }

    // after above step, run call back function()
    callback(cleaned_input);
}
```

Now python uses cleaned country name and grab list of cities from json file. Then query database using country name given, if none is returned (len(result)) < 1, it will call get_aqi function to grab data by performing api call and store it into database. If there is data in database with given country name simply grab it from database and send it off to JS.

```
@app.route("/cities/<country>")
def cities(country):
    """ for given country
    1. get list of cities from json file.
    2. loop through each city and call api to get AQI data.
    3. store into db
    4. return {city:[], aqi:[], lat_lng:[a,b]} so heat map can be made.
    """
    with open('static/db/final_cities_countries.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    # if data exists grab data, if not query again and store into db, then grab data
    query = db.select([Aqi]).where(Aqi.Country == country)
    result = db.engine.execute(query).fetchall()
    if len(result) < 1:
        list_of_cities = data[country]
        for city in list_of_cities:
            # store into db if aqi_call is ONLY successful with status:ok
            if get_aqi(city) != None:
                aqi_response = get_aqi(city)
                lat = aqi_response['data']['city']['geo'][0]
                lng = aqi_response['data']['city']['geo'][1]
                time = aqi_response['data']['time']['s']

                # creating instance of Aqi class(row in MySQL table) and inserting into aqi table
                aqi_data = Aqi(country, city, aqi_response['data']['aqi'], lat, lng, time)
                db.session.add(aqi_data)
                db.session.commit()
        # this time it will have more  
        query = db.select([Aqi]).where(Aqi.Country == country)

        # result = [(id, country, city,...), (id, country, city,...), ...etc.]
        result = db.engine.execute(query).fetchall()

    # sending back list of dictionaries. [{id:x, country:y, city:z, etc...}, {},{},...]
    return jsonify([dict(row) for row in result])
```

So now I have created database with countries that user inputted however once it has been created it stores data from that time and does not get updated. I want it to update every hour.

Addtional question: what happens when user query database while it is updating?

Comment: add some code or work you have done so far such that we can guide you.

Comment: I've updated it, let me know if you need more description. Thanks!

Comment: what I understand is that you want to hit an api on a regular interval, the api will get data from somewhere and update the database?

Comment: yeah, but I want to use each row data from cities column in my database to perform that api call

Comment: so let me rephrase the question, you want to hit an api on a regular interval, the api will get all the cities from the table, for each city it will make api request and update the table ?

Comment: yes. and new rows of data will be added every time user input new country.

Comment: so what part of code you want me to help you with ? The regular hit of api or the api itself ?

Comment: how I can extract column and perform api call then update database

Comment: @hanuelkim I guess you are using flask? what DB are you using and how do you connect to your database (sqlalchemy or something )?

Comment: Yes I am using flask, sqlalchemy and MySQL